# Watchdog timer dll

Tags: labview

Is there any way to invoke the watchdog timer while running applications? I am building an application in LabVIEW for which I want to invoke a system restart if the LabVIEW built application crashes.

Any help. Thanks

Comment: Can you please mention the platform you use? Is it windows or real time target?

Comment: Why would the labview application crash?  Seems like a better idea is to make the application more robust so it won't crash.

Answer (score 1):

If you have NI Real-Time target you can use built-in watchdog functions.

If you are running the application on windows, you should write other application to maintain the first one. So the LabVIEW app would periodically send a bit to your watchdog consumer app.

The best way I think is to evaluate the problem and make your LabVIEW application running stable. For sure there is something in your code that crashes LabVIEW (ex. some queue gets full and your writer endpoint waits infinitely).